# jQuery datepicker displaying a Buddhist date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is there any jQuery datepicker plugin to display as Buddhist date?

Currently I use the [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) datepicker to display it, but it's not actually I want. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker( {
        appendText: ' yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoSize: true,
        buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        showOn: 'both',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            year = dateText.substring(0, 4);
            month = dateText.substring(5, 7);
            day = dateText.substring(8);
            _year = parseInt(year) + 543 + '';
            $(this).val(_year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
        },
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            year = input.value.substring(0, 4);
            month = input.value.substring(5, 7);
            day = input.value.substring(8);
            _year = parseInt(year) - 543 + '';
            $(this).datepicker("setDate", new Date(_year, month - 1, day, 0, 0, 0, 0));
        }
    });
});
```

What I want is when `#datepicker` has no value, the calendar pop up is displaying the current date + 543 years. When `#datepicker` has a value, the calendar pop up is displaying the date in the `#datepicker` value.

The problem is when the selected year is a leap year, for example, 2008-02-29 AD is valid but we can't display 2551-02-29 (Buddhist date) (which is the same date) on that pop up.

**Update 2010-07-30**

According to *[Add support for Thai year format in datepicker module](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4843)* and *[Datepicker: Support non-Gregorian calendars](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/5789)* it seems they plan to create support for non-Gregorian calendars.

Currently I try to use the plugin [jQuery Calendars](http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html) by [Keith Wood](http://keith-wood.name/#default).

Answer (score 5):

You can find my modified version of jQuery DatePicker here:

http://www.anassirk.com/articles/1

The blog is in Thai so I'll briefly explain it below:

Download the plugin here:
http://www.anassirk.com/files/DatePicker.zip

The usage is quite similar to the standard jQuery DatePicker with one extra boolean option named "isBuddhist" which you can set it to true to render the Buddhist calendar.

```
$("#datepicker-th").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', isBuddhist: true, defaultDate: toDay });
```

**important:** in Buddhist mode you have to set the "defaultDate" option to a date string of the format specified in the "dateFormat" option. Like '19/3/2554' for 'dd/mm/yy'

Cheers!

Comment: 13 years later, the link leads me to a gambling site.

Answer (score 1):

I've created plugins for jQuery UI datepicker to make it support the Buddhist Era format.
More details in [jQuery UI datepicker extension for the Buddhist era](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-datepicker-extension-buddhist-era/)