# jQuery datepicker plugin doesn't work in Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, datepicker

I'm using a specific jquery datepicker vidget (http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html). The support for specific calendars (Thai) is the reason. Applying new datepicker to the existing logic I've faced the problem. The picker doesn't open (popup doesn't appear) in Chrome and Safari browsers, while it works fine in IE8 and Firefox.
After some investigation I came to the mind that the attachment subject html tag is the reason. It is written in the reference to the plugin that it is supposed to be attached to ,  and  tags. And I'm attaching it to the  tags. 
Here comes the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.calendars.js?v=$version"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.calendars.plus.js?v=$version"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.calendars.picker.js?v=$version"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.calendars.thai.js?v=$version"></script>

jQuery(function() {
            jQuery('#deactivation_date').calendarsPicker({
                changeMonth: false, 
                showOtherMonths: true, 
                selectOtherMonths: true,
                showAnim: '',
                dateFormat: _dateFormat,
                calendar: jQuery.calendars.instance(_userLanguageCode == 'th' ? 'thai' : '', 'en'),
                alignment: 'bottom',
                renderer: jQuery.extend({}, jQuery.calendars.picker.defaultRenderer,
                    {
                        picker: jQuery.calendars.picker.defaultRenderer.picker.
                        replace(/\{link:prev\}/, '{link:prevJump}{link:prev}').
                        replace(/\{link:next\}/, '{link:nextJump}{link:next}').
                        replace(/\{link:clear\}/, '').
                        replace(/\{link:close\}/, '')
                    }),
                onSelect: function(dates){

                        }
                    }
            });
        });
```

...

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="date-pick no-left-padding" id = "deactivation_date">
   "DateText" </a>
```

Further investigation made me think that in Chrome the appropriate event handler is not attached correctly, because debugger doesn't even step into "show" function. This is the probable part of widget that fails in Chrome and Safari:

```
var trigger = inst.get('showTrigger');
inst.trigger = (!trigger ? $([]) :
        $(trigger).clone().addClass(this._triggerClass)
        [inst.get('isRTL') ? 'insertBefore' : 'insertAfter'](target).
            click(function() {
            if (!$.calendars.picker.isDisabled(target[0])) {
                $.calendars.picker[$.calendars.picker.curInst == inst ?
                    'hide' : 'show'](target[0]);
            }
        }));
```

There is a variant to reattach all the datepickers to different tags, but for div/span the inline rendering will be performed, and input doesn't look like text at all.

Please share your ideas, if any...

Thanks in advance

**jQuery datepicker** seems not to support non-Gregorian calendars at the moment:
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5789
Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

probably is not completely an answer to your question but an hint to solve your problem.

Why not using the standard JQuery UI calendar with the globalization files you can find [here](https://github.com/jquery/globalize)?

Comment: After some investigation I still doubt if it supports local calendars. But I've just come across this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297652/jquery-datepicker-displaying-a-buddhist-date. So I'll try. Thanks, Mauro

Comment: Dear godspeed I am not a big expert of Thai calendars sorry! Is it just an offset in year?

Comment: Yes it is. The offset is 543 years. There's also some magic with leap years, but I've just tested the keith-wood plugin and it doesn't seem to prevent displaying Feb 29th.